# How to merge structure of two DataTables into one c#?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, nullreferenceexception

I have two data tables and want merge columns and create as third table.
Do not want to lose `ExtendedProperties` so not Selecting DataColumn.ColumnName and adding as columns.

**Code:**

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.TableName = "dt1";
dt1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns.Add("A") };
dt1.Columns.Add("B");
dt1.Columns.Add("C");
dt1.Columns.Add("D");

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.TableName = "dt2";
dt2.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt2.Columns.Add("a") };
dt2.Columns.Add("b");
dt2.Columns.Add("c");
dt2.Columns.Add("d");

var dtResult = dt1.Clone();
dtResult.TableName = "dtResult";
```

Working fine till here

Now want to merge...

**Multiple merge tries type 1**

```
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone()); 
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey); 
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
```

In all above tries, Columns are `merged` into dtResult but throws `NullReferenceException`.
StackTrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeSchema(DataTable table)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTableData(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTable(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Merge(DataTable table, Boolean preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction)
   at Demo.Program.Test5() in C:\App\Demo\Program.cs:line 54
   at Demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\App\Program.cs:line 36
```

**Multiple merge tries type 2**

```
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false, MissingSchemaAction.Error);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true, MissingSchemaAction.Error);
```

In all above tries, Columns are `NOT merged` into dtResult and `System.Data.DataException`
StackTrace:

```
System.Data.DataException
  HResult=0x80131920
  Message=Target table  missing definition for column a.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeSchema(DataTable table)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTableData(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.Merger.MergeTable(DataTable src)
   at System.Data.DataTable.Merge(DataTable table, Boolean preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction)
   at Demo.Program.Test5() in C:\App\Demo\Program.cs:line 54
   at Demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\App\Demo\Program.cs:line 36
```

**Multiple merge tries type 3**

```
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone(), true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
```

In all above tries, Columns are `NOT merged` into dtResult and `NO exception`

Comment: Well, I am looking for the use of ```DataTable.Merge(DataTable table, Boolean preserveChanges, MissingSchemaAction missingSchemaAction)```

Comment: You really need use debugger to find out which line throws an exception! Might be: `dtResult` is must be null?

Comment: I think try catch block will not solve your problem, you need to have a look at the reason of *null*

Comment: I added try-catch 
```
var dtResult = dt1.Clone();
try
{
 dtResult.Merge(dt2.Clone());
}catch(NullReferenceException ex)
{

}
```

After try catch, dtResult have all the required column.

Comment: dt1, dt2, dtResult, non of these are null. Also in StackTrace ```Merger.MergeSchema``` has problem which means ```dtResult``` is NOT null. In my code there's already null check for ```dt2```.

Comment: @brian-rasmussen

Comment: Unfortunelty the question is closed! But you can post an another question for as: `How to merge two datatables` which proper code